# Can you have a permanent become all permanent types at the same time?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is there any combination of cards that could make a permanent all permanent types simultaneously? (planeswalker, land, creature, artifact, enchantment). I'm hitting a roadblock making something a planeswalker AND a land.

Comment: I know this is only tangentially related, but there is actually a way to have a permanent with no permanent types.  See the rulings on Neurok Transmuter for that fun interaction.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Yes**

Play [Gideon Blackblade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%20Blackblade%5d). He will be both a creature and a planeswalker on your turn.

Play [Mycosynth Lattice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMycosynth%20Lattice%5d) to turn it (and everything) into an artifact.

Play [Enchanted Evening](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEnchanted%20Evening%5d) to turn it (and everything) into an enchantment.

Play [Xenograft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bXenograft%5d), naming saproling, to give all your creatures the saproling creature type.

Play [Life and Limb](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLife%20and%20Limb%5d) to turn the Gideon Saproling into a land (forest) as well.

I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but this might involve some of the least complicated rules.

It's worth mentioning that there are other types that can apply to permanents:
Basic, Snow, Tribal, and a few other silver-bordered ones.

---

If you add a [March of the Machines](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarch%20of%20the%20Machines%5d), *everything* is a Artifact Enchantment Creature, and your permanents are Artifact Enchantment Creature Lands - Forest Saproling. Be careful, as this will probably destroy your lands (well, your land cards in play, since they have CMC 0 and will be 0/0 creatures. I believe Forests will be OK, remaining at 1/1 creatures.)
Any planeswalker you play from that point on will be a Legendary Artifact Enchantment Creature Planeswalker Land.

Comment: I think in order to pull off what OP wanted you have to start with a Planeswalker because (AFAIK) there isn't a way to turn a non-planeswalker permanent into a planeswalker without copying it.  Also, the only basic type that we're missing (outside of Instant and Sorcery because they can't exist on the battlefield) is Tribal.  We'd probably have to figure out a way to copy one of the Tribal Artifacts or Enchantments onto the Gideon without overwriting the previous alterations, copy effects are probably out of the question.

Comment: Tribal isn't a permanent type, so we're fine. (It can go on permanents, but it can also go on non-permanent, so it's not a permanent type. )

Comment: For a rules reference for that, rule 110.4 explicitly lists the 5 permanent types.

Comment: Now with the new "Battle" type, while you can't get a permanent of all six types, you can get an Artifact Enchantment Land Creature Battle. (As far as I can see)